# Reading from a PHP array in JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I seem to have trouble with getting data from a php array, I've looked at various examples of how to do this but I must be missing something because I can not get my code to work.

**PHP method**

```
function getLatestActivity(){
   $messages = array( 
      array('id'=>'01', 'value'=>'blah'),
      array('id'=>'02', 'value'=>'Oil'),
      array('id'=>'03', 'value'=>'Spark') 
   );

   echo json_encode($messages); 
   return;  
}
```

**AJAX get functiom**

```
function getLatestActivities(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET", url: "include/process.php", 
      data:{
         getLatestActivity: "true",
         toUser: "4",
         ignoreMessages:"1",
         dataType: "json"
      },
      success: function(data){
         $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
            alert(data.id);
         });              
      }
   });   
}
```

The alert prints out the message "undefined", any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with - it's your single object now:

```
alert(elem.id);
```

Comment: Check, what is in `data` before `$.each()`.

Comment: if I write "alert(data);" instead of the $.each() i get 

[{"id":"01","value":"blah"},{"id":"02","value":"Oil"},{"id":"03","value":"Spark"}]

Comment: So it has to be in `elem` variable.

Comment: If i write alert(elem) it prints out each character separately, e.g. [ { "

Comment: Add to `$.ajax()`:  `dataType: "json"`

Comment: I have put [dataType: "json"] in the ajax part

Comment: This is not the place for ajax request parameters - in `data{}` you just set data you want to send. You have to put it directly in `ajax({})`

Comment: Ahh of course, I can't believe I did that, your help was much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It is quite likely that data isn't what you're expecting. You aren't setting any headers in your response, and as hinted at by @Sudesh dataType isn't in the right place. The result is that data is most likely a string because jquery will not parse it as json.

You're also referring to the wrong variable. `data.id` cannot exist with the data you are returning from php. you would need `elem.id` or if you prefer `data[i].id` if data did contain what you're expecting. As an aside - using $.each instead of a for loop is relatively inefficient.

You can check if that's the case with code such as:

```
function getLatestActivities(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "GET", url: "include/process.php", 
      data:{
         getLatestActivity: "true",
         toUser: "4",
         ignoreMessages:"1",
         dataType: "json"
      },
      success: function(data){
         console.log(data); // <- look at the response
         $.each(data, function (i, elem) {
            // alert(data.id); don't debug using alerts
            console.log(elem);
         });              
      }
   });   
}
```

If data is a string (or simply, not what you're expecting) this should get you closer:

```
function getLatestActivity(){
    ....
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($messages); 
}
```

with

```
function getLatestActivities(){
   $.ajax({
      url: "include/process.php", 
      data:{
         getLatestActivity: true,
         toUser: 4,
         ignoreMessages:1,
      },
      success: function(data){
         console.log(data);           
         ...              
      }
   });   
}
```

`data` should at least then be an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think dataType should not be part of data object rather should be sibling of success (options). I believe you are not getting data as JSON object rather just string because of it